# Nest js optional body parameter

Tags: javascript, nestjs

Hi i have nest app dto:

```
export class TestDto {
  @IsNotEmpty()
  id: number;

  @IsNotEmpty()
  slug: string;

  @IsNotEmpty()
  size: number;
}
```

and Post request:

```
  @Post(':id/start')
  async startTest(
    @Param('id') id: number,
    @Request() req,
    @Body() testDto?: TestDto
  ): Promise<RoomDto | string> {
    return await this.roomsService.startTest(id, testDto);
  }
```

I want to have testDto from body optional but instead i have an error when sending request:

```
{
    "statusCode": 400,
    "message": [
        "slug should not be empty",
        "size should not be empty"
    ],
    "error": "Bad Request"
}
```

How to achieve something like this?

Answer (score 4):

You have to change the IsNotEmpty decorator to IsOptional, when you add the question mark to a parameter you're telling Typescript that that value can be undefined and that doesn't matter in the running time.

You can check the allowed decorators here: https://github.com/typestack/class-validator#validation-decorators

The result DTO will be something like this:

```js
export class TestDto {
  @IsNotEmpty()
  id: number;

  @IsOptional()
  slug?: string;

  @IsOptional()
  size?: number;
}
```

Remember to import IsOptional from class-validator package.

Comment: Just stumbled upon this question when searching if I have to use **both** `@IsOptional` decorator with the question mark in the parameter to make it optional in the DTO? If yes, is there a plausible reason for that, or it's just the so-called _syntactic sugar_?

Comment: You use the decorator to perform the validation on the dto and the question mark to tell typescript that is an optional value so it can interact better when you're coding.